# What kind of spider is this from New Zealand?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

This is biggest one I have caught so far:

[image]

They would occasionally walk into my house and wait for the night to go out and about.

Comment: The features are fairly generic. It is probably a house spider, genus Badumna

Comment: Please let it go free. It shares this living space with you!!

Comment: Spiders are much more likely to be highly beneficial to you than to be harmful. Please consider leaving them alone, or if you can't, catch and release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the limited info and only a side image (top/bottom photos more helpful for ID), it's hard to pinpoint a specific species. To complicate matters, [Manaaki Whenua Landcare research](https://www.landcareresearch.co.nz/discover-our-research/biodiversity/plants-invertebrates-fungi-and-bacteria/invertebrate-systematics/spiders/) suggests:

> Over 90% of New Zealand spiders are endemic, the rest are natural introductions through windborne or human activities. The species we frequently see around are houses and gardens are usually introduced species. Most of the endemic species are restricted to native habitats, from forest to alpine regions

One possible group are the sheetweb spiders (family [Stiphidiidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiphidiidae)).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiphidiidae), most species are speckled brown with long legs with a body length < 2.5 cm and leg-span < 15 cm. This family of spiders is nocturnal, and they can be found in gardens or (ales) even enter homes.

Here's an example specimen from this family:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Manaaki Whenua Landcare research](https://www.landcareresearch.co.nz/discover-our-research/biodiversity/plants-invertebrates-fungi-and-bacteria/invertebrate-systematics/spiders/)</sup>

According to [Arachne.org.au](http://www.arachne.org.au/01_cms/details.asp?ID=2349), the *Stiphidion* genus is the most commonly seen group from this family.

- Their image of a female *Stiphidion*, also closely resembles yours:

[image]

<sup>Credit: Dr Greg Anderson, Source: [Arachne.org.au](http://www.arachne.org.au/01_cms/details.asp?ID=2349)</sup>